# Joomla 3 Module creation via PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a PHP script that is running a ton of updates on a Joomla site as it migrates from 1.5 to 3.x... updating, creating and deleting menu items, modules, etc. All is well, but I'm running into an issue with the "_assets" database table. When creating a module, it has an entry in the _assets table that lines up with the entry in the _modules table. The "rules" for the item in the _assets table looks very similar to "params" for items in the _modules table, meaning it is a collection of parameters within a set of { } curly brackets. The difference for assets is that they contain { } parameters INSIDE of the overall { }. I think that is the source of the issue here for me.

Example "rules" for an asset from database:

```
{"core.create":{"6":1,"3":1},"core.delete":{"6":1},"core.edit":{"6":1,"4":1},"core.edit.state":{"6":1,"5":1},"core.edit.own":{"6":1,"3":1}}
```

Script is using this:

```
$asset_params1 = "{\"core.create\":{\"6\":1,\"3\":1},\"core.delete\":{\"6\":1},\"core.edit\":{\"6\":1,\"4\":1},\"core.edit.state\":{\"6\":1,\"5\":1},\"core.edit.own\":{\"6\":1,\"3\":1}}";
```

I've used this same type of setup for loading params of other non-asset items and it works fine. This portion however gives me "1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax...". Like I said, I think it's related to the {} inside of other {}. That's how Joomla has it, so not sure what to modify here to make it work. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I really would not touch this if you do not know what you are doing. If you leave the rules empty they will just inherit the rules from com_modules and that is going to be fine, it was fine for the first 7 years of joomla and it's fine for 99.9% of all websites. The text inside your record is not going to give you a sql syntax error, a problem in your sql is going to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, turns out I was missing one ' single quote. That's not what the error details were pointing to, but found that... fixed it... now it is working as expected. Thanks!